# Navigate ng-grid rows using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-grid

I want to scroll across ng-grid rows using arrow keys and select the row when space button is clicked..

I have tried what is suggested in this link.
http://www.pedaldrivenprogramming.com/2014/10/making-ng-grid-scroll-and-select-naturally-with-arrow-keys/

But nothing seems working..Can anyone help?

Comment: The link you provided also seems to be not working :)

Comment: The plunkr was not working.But i tried the code that was mentioned in that link.I dont have any idea of how and where to start for this.Do you have any link or reference that you can help me with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,my bad.I forgot to add enableCellSelection on my grid after which, i am able to navigate my grid